# Custom Taxonomy list: how to make "choose from most used" default to open, checklist

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm doing a site for a wine importer. The wines have many custom taxonomies (type of wine, import/domestic, etc.)

When adding a wine, the taxonomies show up in the right column but not the way I'd like. The default is a form input field with a link under that says: "Choose from most used *taxonomyname*"

I'd like the taxonomies to show up as a checklist. Or at least with the clickable tag cloud to default to open.

The point here is I'd like to save my client from having to click to create a tag cloud every time.

Any way to do this? Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 2):

The default UI view for a hierarchical custom taxonomy is a series of checkboxes. It sounds like wine taxonomies have a *one-to-many* relationship so you should be set.

If you are registering your taxonomy using PHP add `hierarchical => true` to your configuration options.

```
register_taxonomy( 'xxx', 'post', array( ... **'hierarchical' => true** , ...) ); } ?>
```

If you are using a plugin there should be an option to set a taxonomy to hierarchical.